# Spin a local database with Kubernetes and Rancher

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, rancher

How do you change the cockroachdb YAML configuration from Rancher catalog that it will just

- Use local disk (testing on a local computer)
- Just use 1GB of disk space (should be enough for testing)

Here's the complete YAML

```yaml
clusterDomain: cluster.local
conf:
  attrs: []
  cache: 25%
  cluster-name: ''
  disable-cluster-name-verification: false
  http-port: 8080
  join: []
  locality: ''
  logtostderr: INFO
  max-disk-temp-storage: 0
  max-offset: 500ms
  max-sql-memory: 25%
  port: 26257
  single-node: false
  sql-audit-dir: ''
image:
  credentials: {}
  pullPolicy: IfNotPresent
  repository: cockroachdb/cockroach
  tag: v20.1.3
ingress:
  annotations: {}
  enabled: false
  hosts: []
  labels: {}
  paths:
    - /
  tls: []
init:
  affinity: {}
  annotations: {}
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: init
  nodeSelector: {}
  resources: {}
  tolerations: []
labels: {}
networkPolicy:
  enabled: false
  ingress:
    grpc: []
    http: []
service:
  discovery:
    annotations: {}
    labels:
      app.kubernetes.io/component: cockroachdb
  ports:
    grpc:
      external:
        name: grpc
        port: 26257
      internal:
        name: grpc-internal
        port: 26257
    http:
      name: http
      port: 8080
  public:
    annotations: {}
    labels:
      app.kubernetes.io/component: cockroachdb
    type: ClusterIP
statefulset:
  annotations: {}
  args: []
  budget:
    maxUnavailable: 1
  env: []
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: cockroachdb
  nodeAffinity: {}
  nodeSelector: {}
  podAffinity: {}
  podAntiAffinity:
    type: soft
    weight: 100
  podManagementPolicy: Parallel
  priorityClassName: ''
  replicas: 3
  resources: {}
  secretMounts: []
  tolerations: []
  updateStrategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
storage:
  hostPath: ''
  persistentVolume:
    annotations: {}
    enabled: true
    labels: {}
    size: 100Gi
    storageClass: ''
tls:
  certs:
    clientRootSecret: cockroachdb-root
    nodeSecret: cockroachdb-node
    provided: false
    tlsSecret: false
  enabled: false
  init:
    image:
      credentials: {}
      pullPolicy: IfNotPresent
      repository: cockroachdb/cockroach-k8s-request-cert
      tag: '0.4'
  serviceAccount:
    create: true
    name: ''
Storage: 100Gi
```

Answer (score 1):

## Storage Size

It looks like `Storage` and `store.persistentVolume.size` can both be set to `1Gi` if you are looking for one gigabyte of storage.

## Local Storage

Then, I would check if you have a storageClass by running `kubectl get storageClass`. Many times, cluters come with the [local-path-provisioner](https://github.com/rancher/local-path-provisioner) storageClass. If you have that, I would try setting `store.persistentVolume.storageClass` to the name of the local path proversion storageClass you have installed on your system. If you don't have that or an alternative, I would consider installing it.

## More Info

I'm not certain, but it's possible that it is using [this helm chart](https://github.com/cockroachdb/helm-charts/tree/master/cockroachdb) to install the database. This section of the chart deals with the volume claim managment, so I would look here if you need to do more troubleshooting: https://github.com/cockroachdb/helm-charts/blob/master/cockroachdb/templates/statefulset.yaml#L376